# Using BufferedReader to count rows in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, file-io, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I'm using BufferedReader to read a .csv file.  I have no problem reading the file and extracting the data.  However, the problem that I do have is that I have to hard-code my array declaration.  For example:

```
        String[][] numbers=new String[5258][16];
```

The .csv file I was using had  5258 rows and 16 columns.  I'd like to be able to do something like this though:

```
        String[][] numbers=new String[rowsInFile][16];
```

In other words, I want the variable 'rowsInFile' to be equivalent to the amount of rows in the file (I don't want to count the columns, because every .csv file I will be running through this program has 16 columns).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        String fileInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                "Please enter the path of the CSV file to read:");

        File file = new File(fileInput);

        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;

        //get rows in the file
        int rowsInFile = 0;
        while(bufRdr.readLine() != null) {
            rowsInFile++;
            row++;
        }
        String[][] numbers=new String[rowsInFile][16];

        //read each line of text file
        row = 0;
        while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            col=0;

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
```

However, I'm getting a null pointer exception.  Any ideas of what I should do?

P.S.  Yes, this code is surrounded by a try/catch statement.

Comment: What line is throwing the NPE, nothing in the code you posted looks suspicious.

Comment: Sorry to sound so novice, but I'm actually not even sure how to check.  If I click on the error displayed, it just brings up a new window entitled "Create breakpoint for java.lang.NullPointerException".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, once you go through the `BufferedReader` once, you can't go back through it again. In other words, you have to use a new `BufferedReader`.

```
bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
row = 0;
while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
```

Alternatively, you could use a dynamic array structure like an `ArrayList<String[]>` or a `LinkedList<String[]>` to store the rows.

```
LinkedList<String[]> numbers = new LinkedList<String[]>();

while( (line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null ) {
    numbers.add(line.split(","));
}
```

Then instead of doing `numbers[i][j]`, you use `numbers.get(i)[j]`.

Comment: I tried adding bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  after String[][] numbers=new String[rowsInFile][16];  again to create a new BufferedReader, but I'm still getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Also, I'm a little unfamiliar with using Lists.  Would you mind explaining how I could use them to store the rows?

Comment: @Mike Gates: Hm, that's strange. Anywho, I edited my answer to include an example using `LinkedList`.

Comment: I accepted your answer, however I still can't seem to be able to convert from a list to a string[][].

Comment: `String[][] arr = new String[numbers.size()][]; for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = numbers.get(i);`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array use something dynamic like a List.   For example:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Also using String's `split()` method will simplify the loading of the row.

Comment: I'm actually unfamiliar with using a List.  I've seen it before but I've never used it.  Would you mind elaborating a little more please?

Comment: @mike-gates See the tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that BufferedReaders work by reading until the end of a file, and then they get stuck there. Your code requires reading through the file twice, but because you already reached an EOF, the BufferedReader is stuck returning null. I tend to solve this by stuffing the lines into an ArrayList, and using the size() method to get the number of lines. The source code looks something like this:

```
    int rowsInFile=0;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tmp = "";
    while(tmp=bugRdr.readLine())
    {
        lines.add(tmp);
    }

    rowsInFile = lines.size();
    String[][] numbers = new String[rowsInFile][16];

    int row = 0;
    for(String line : lines)
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        col=0;

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //get next token and store it in the array
            numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }
```